# Unable to update Ubuntu 12.04: Connection refused

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I am unable to update my current version of Ubuntu. Here is the output of sudo apt-get update:

```
Err http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg            
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.15). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg    
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Reading package lists... Done                        
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.15). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is the content of /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130820.1)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-proposed restricted main universe
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory is empy.
Is there anyway I can update Ubuntu without going throug the CD installation

Comment: Try using a different mirror. It might be something temporary.

Comment: I tried multiple mirrors. None have been successful so far

Comment: Ok, to test things out, what does `wget -S http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/Release.gpg` say?

Comment: Same thing: Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|2001:67c:1360:8c01::19|:80... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: IPv6? O.o Try `apt-get update -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true`.

Comment: I fixed the issue! I had to use a proxy. Thanks a lot for your time though, I truly appreciate it :)

Comment: @kenorb: That looks like the reverse issue, i. e. a proxy is (ill-)configured when it shouldn't be, while this question is about a missing proxy configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the file: /etc/apt/apt.conf

Entered the following line:

```
 acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:8080";
```